# Unit testing an ionic3 project with external javascript dependecies

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

I have an ionic app that uses google maps and wicket JS libraries. 
In the index.html, I have

```
<script src="assets/wicket.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&libraries=drawing,places"></script>
```

and everything is working as it should when running the app in emulator or ionic serve, but when unit testing a component with a map, I am getting "google is not defined" error on the line

```
let location = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
```

I am guessing that's because I am missing the js references in the testing config, but I have no idea where and how to include them. 
Does anyone know where in the testing config to include these? (I have been following the https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-unit-test-an-ionic-2-application/ tutorial to add unit tests to my existing app).

Thanks,
Yuval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is mock the dependencies, in this case google maps lib or `google` object.

You can use a library or create some mock services. In this case I would try to find a good mock library maybe this : https://github.com/sttts/google-maps-mock it's not ionic-specific but maybe it will work.

Also try instead of using a local variable in a function to instantiate in a lifecycle hook for example onInit
`this.location = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);` to be able to test it easier.

I found here https://github.com/chrisgriffith/ionic-native-mocks/blob/master/package.json something useful `"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.3",`

Comment: let me know if you need some more help